# How to share pre-configured widgets when wrapping seems not possible

Tags: flutter

I have this flutter button:

```
RaisedButton(
    elevation: 2,
    color: Colors.lightBlue,
    child: Text('Add'),
    onPressed: () {
      appState.addSet();
    },
)
```

I have many of those buttons having the same property elevation value '2' set. I do not want to define this value every time everywhere I create a RaisedButton.

Then I thought about wrapping this RaisedButton with a new StatelessWidget and some parameters.

But then I saw that every onPressed even is executing a function with dynamic type definition:

could be a void method or having a parameter value etc... That means how can I offer a ctor parameter

e.g. function that covers both type definitions?

Or maybe in flutter I can somehow overwrite the styles - don`t speak of fonts/colors - that all RaisedButton classes have the same elevation?

Comment: AFAIK we can't give generic type for parameter in Flutter, I just give Function() as the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of flutter is the it's widgets,  you can just extend the `RaisedButton` class and pass params to super class(`RaisedButton` here) & default the values incase on no input.

Example:

```
class MyRaisedButton extends RaisedButton {
  const MyRaisedButton({
    Key key,
    @required VoidCallback onPressed,
    Color color,
    double elevation,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          elevation: elevation ?? 2,
          color: color ?? Colors.lightBlue,
          child: child ?? const Text('Button'),
        );
}
```

Use `MyRaisedButton` instead of `RaisedButton`. This gives you the same functionalities if a `RaisedButton` except that default values will be used when you don't pass args.

Hope that helps!